# Removing console.log from React Native app in release (production) using yarn and npm for performance improvement

Tags: android, reactjs, node.js, react-native, console

Using console.log statements is one of the most common patterns to debug in JavaScript applications in general, including React Native apps. Leaving the console statements in the source code when publishing React Native apps can cause some big bottlenecks in the JavaScript thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save-dev
yarn add babel-plugin-transform-remove-console -D
```

**Edit babel.config.js**

```
 module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ["transform-remove-console"],     //removing consoles.log from app during release (production) versions
    },
  },
};
```

**OR .babelrc**

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put these line in `index.js` file:

```
if (!__DEV__) {
  console.log = () => {}
}
```